# LogLog regression line is not straight with negative log values?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, regression

I have a correlation plot, where I am trying to show the values in loglog scale. I am trying to show the line of best fit as well on the correlation plot.

The following is my code.

```
import numpy             as np
import matplotlib        as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy import stats

def loglogplot(seed):
    mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
    figh, figw = 1.80118*2, 1.80118*2    
    fig, axes  = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(figh, figw))

    axes.set_xscale('log')
    axes.set_yscale('log')

    np.random.seed(seed)
    x = 10 ** np.random.uniform(-3, 3, size=1000*4)
    y = x * 10 ** np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=1000*4)
    axes.scatter(x, y, color='black', s=10, alpha=0.1)

    logx = np.log10(x)
    logy = np.log10(y)

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(logx, logy)
    xps = np.arange(10**-4, 10**4, 1)
    axes.plot(xps, slope * xps + intercept, color='red', lw=2)    

    axes.set_xlim((10**-4, 10**4))
    axes.set_ylim((10**-4, 10**4))

    plt.show()
```

When run with `loglogplot(seed=5)` I get the following image.

[image: LogLog function invocation with seed=5]

When run with `loglogplot(seed=10)` I get the following image.

[image: LogLog function invocation with seed=5]

I am preplexed as to why, the regression line is not plotted as a straight line before x=1. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Changed `xps = np.arange(10**-4, 10**4, 1)` to `xps = np.logspace(-4, 4, 1000)`, and the result is no better qualitatively.

Seed = 5 gives:

[image: LogSpace points between -4 and 4 for seed=5]

Seed = 10 gives:

[image: LogSpace points between -4 and 4 for seed=10]

Comment: Try generating xps with `np.logspace(-4,4,N)` instead of `np.arange`.

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't help much. Check the edit in the question for images resulting from the changes.

Comment: you need to transform your best-fit parameters back into their original units

Comment: I am sorry, could you show where exactly am I supposed to do that? I think I am plotting everything in log transformed space itself, and things more or less are the same.

Comment: `slope * xps + intercept` is not performed in log space

Comment: True, but my x and y axis is on log scales anyway, for the purposes of plotting like I said. Moreover, the points are showing up linearly too. It's the straight line that is curving at x < 1.

Comment: log scales don't transform the data, they transform where the data show up in paper space, does that make sense?

Comment: "log scales don't transform the data, they transform where the data show up in paper space" <-- this is what I didn't know. I thought setting up the scales did the transformation while/before/during the plotting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of the issue here is that **log scales don't transform the data**, but instead they **transform where the data show up in paper space**. This means, you can't take log-transformed best-fit parameters and use them on non-log-transformed data, and plot it correctly.

You either need to log-transform your data, and use them directly, or you need to think about the relationship you've actually modeled and (undo it as necessary).

By fitting the logs of the data you've fit the following equation:

```
log(y) = m * log(x) + p
```

Using math, that turns into:

```
y = exp(p) * (x ^ m)
```

So your code becomes:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import rcParams, pyplot
from scipy import stats

def loglogplot(seed):
    rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
    figh, figw = 1.80118*2, 1.80118*2    
    fig, axes  = pyplot.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(figh, figw))

    axes.set_xscale('log')
    axes.set_yscale('log')

    numpy.random.seed(seed)
    x = 10 ** numpy.random.uniform(-3, 3, size=1000*4)
    y = x * 10 ** numpy.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=1000*4)
    axes.scatter(x, y, color='black', s=10, alpha=0.1)

    logx = numpy.log(x)  # <-- doesn't matter that we use natural log
    logy = numpy.log(y)  #     so long as we're consistent

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(logx, logy)
    xhat = numpy.logspace(-4, 4, 1000)
    yhat = numpy.exp(intercept) * xhat ** slope  # exp -> consistency
    axes.plot(xhat, yhat, color='red', lw=2)    

    axes.set_xlim((10**-4, 10**4))
    axes.set_ylim((10**-4, 10**4))

    return fig
```

[image]